# How to backup root and reinstall Linux after extending partition in dual boot with windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

[Here's my Gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXURM.png)

Here's what I want to do.

I have windows 10 already installed before I had Ubuntu installed.
The problem is I had miscalculated the space and reserved only 40Gb for Ubuntu as I was installing it.
Now I have over 40Gb in the hard drive after the Ubuntu partition, GPart shows it AFTER the ubuntu partition,  to its right. But I can't get my home partition to extend to it. Guides mention that I have to do it from a live cd.

I just want to be able to use that space with my Linux partition.
Here's where I hit a snag. Most of the guides here mention is it a risky business and that GRUB might break as I have to do all of the steps from a live cd and move my Root around.

Do I really have to do it that way? I can't risk losing access to my machine, especially not Windows. I don't really care about personal files on Linux (I have none), except for the settings I have.
So if grub does break, will it affect my Windows install?

How do I go about backing up and reinstalling the Linux partition after extending my Linux partition?

Thanks

Comment: You are far too worried about this There are 2 live sessions we all should have: a live Ubuntu (it is the one you installed from and you can run boot repair from it when needed) and a live gparted. That last one you can use to shrink and enlarge partitions regardless what is on it. But as always: made a backup of --all-- your personal files before messing with partitions. Don't bother backuping up the OS itself. It is easier to reinstall that.

Comment: by the last one you mean the one that I will have to live boot from a usb, correct? 
Also I am not worried about my files. I dont have anything I need on Ubuntu, although I have the kde desktop installed, which I am worried will lose settings, it took me a long time to setup.

Comment: If you show us a screen shot from GParted displaying the drives partitions and the output of lsblk we can give you step by step instructions to achieve what you want. Whilst it is possible to mess up the system doing this it’s not very likely and it’s all fixable as long as you backup any data you cannot afford to lose

Comment: sure I will, thanks a bunch

Comment: @obadul024 I would do this: 1 partition for windows system (no idea how much that wants ;)) and 1 for Ubuntu system (20Gb is enough). Then create a 3rd partition as large as possible as ntfs. Then store all personal files on that disk. Leave the 2 1st partitions as is (void of personal data). Be certain to have a backup of personal data.

Comment: backup the whole disk with clonezilla (free)

Comment: @Rinzwind I like your solution but my situation is a bit comlicated. I only use Linux for development purposes and so I have a lot of environment files and packages installed. Which if I were to install on a separate drive would drive me nuts figuring out the paths and environment variables. However, as you suggested, I used a Live GPart CD and added all that space I had. So I have solved the issue without any major loss of files. Thanks a bunch for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear but this will give you about 86GB of space for Ubuntu:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose. You are going to delete the sda8 partition so copy off anything you need from there.
2. Using your install media boot into the live environment (Try Ubuntu not install Ubuntu)
3. Using GParted in the live environment delete sda8. This will create unallocated space to the right of sda7. Apply the change.
4. Using GParted resize sda7 making use of all the unallocated space. Apply the change and reboot to the normal Ubuntu system.

I don’t think you will need to reinstall Ubuntu. You appear to have a working system and resizing the partition should not break it.

Good luck

Comment: Yes thanks, I did that exact same thing, but instead of using a Ubuntu env I used the GPart env from a usb drive, which didn't work when I made it using the Media maker in Ubuntu but it worked and I was able to see it in the boot options when I used RUFUS on WINDOWS.

Comment: Yes the GParted live environment is perfect for this but most people who have installed Ubuntu have Ubuntu install media available and that’s just as good for this purpose. Glad it helped.